# Organizing nav bar div elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What I basically need is to take `HEADER-TITLE` div to the top full width of the page & the class `OFFICIAL` with the "official website" text at the bottom of `header-title`, one stacked of other and `EN dropdown` to the right side of header title but at the same `inline block`.

[image: LIKE this photo i need to be]

```css
.header-title {
  background-color: white !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body class="en ch  homepage" style="background-image: url(&quot;./images/body-pattern.jpg&quot;);">
  <header id="headerInternas" class="home">
    <div class="header-top">
      <nav class="idioma dropdown">
        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle ico_idioma" data-toggle="dropdown" itemprop="potentialAction"><span class="flag en"></span>
         EN
         <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mireserva">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropMenu" role="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="idiomas" rel="alternate" hreflang="es">
                <div class="bandera"><span class="flag es"></span></div>
                <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">SPANISH
           </span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-default" class="idiomas">
                <div class="bandera"><span class="flag en"></span></div>
                <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">ENGLISH
         <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="idiomas" rel="alternate" hreflang="de">
                <div class="bandera"><span class="flag de"></span></div>
                <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">GERMAN
      </span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="header-extra hidden-xs">
            <div class="official">
              <i class="fa fa-certificate"></i><span id="web-oficial">Official Website</span>
              <h1 id="nombre-hotel">
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="header-title"><span>official website</span></div>
    </div>
```

Need to achieve from css no touching html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your CSS and your attempts to solve this problem yourself before asking for help. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) has information about how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is very helpful for getting quality responses.

Comment: sean i have update my code.

Comment: Please take another look at the guide on creating an MCVE.

Comment: Your html is invalid too - you have nested anchors

Comment: this all i have

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrapp your  inside your .header-title div

Comment: what you mean with wrapp?

Answer (score 0):

i meant this:

```
 <header id="headerInternas" class="home">
<div class="header-top">
  <div class="header-title">
  <nav class="idioma dropdown">
    <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle ico_idioma" data-toggle="dropdown" 
     itemprop="potentialAction"><span class="flag en"></span>
     EN
     <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mireserva">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropMenu" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="idiomas" rel="alternate" hreflang="es">
            <div class="bandera"><span class="flag es"></span></div>
            <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">SPANISH
       </span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-default" class="idiomas">
            <div class="bandera"><span class="flag en"></span></div>
            <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">ENGLISH
     <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="idiomas" rel="alternate" hreflang="de">
            <div class="bandera"><span class="flag de"></span></div>
            <div class="idioma-texto"><span class="idiomasText">GERMAN
  </span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-extra hidden-xs">
        <div class="official">
          <i class="fa fa-certificate"></i><span id="web-oficial">Official Website</span>
          <h1 id="nombre-hotel">
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer is no valid. i need to achieve fron css no html,

Comment: then add an z-index of -1 to your header-title so it will be in the background